# How to Order by with 2 column in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

this is the sample table

```
name | group
 a   |   2
 b   |   1
 c   |   1
 d   |   2
 e   |   4
 f   |   3
 g   |   4
```

how to order the data with name asc and group asc like this table

```
name | group
 a   |   2
 d   |   2
 b   |   1
 c   |   1
 e   |   4
 g   |   4
 f   |   3
```

i already try with

```
select * from table order by name asc, group asc
```

and the result is not like my expectation

Comment: sorry, i already edit my question, so my purpose, i want to order by name first and with group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to order by *groups* but based on the first name in the group.  You can use window functions:

```
order by min(name) over (partition by group) asc,
         group asc,
         name
```

Note that `group` is a very poor name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.  You should probably use a different name for the column.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4dd19596501ae71fbe9ac77ac7c4d04f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY "group" DESC, name;
```

That is, you want to first sort *descending* by the `group` column, then *ascending* by the `name` column.  Note that the default sort order is ascending, so typically we don't write `ASC`.  Also, `GROUP` is a reserved SQL keyword, and you should avoid naming your columns with this name.